# How do I change the api addresses in the build of the React project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my React project, I want to change the api addresses after build it.
I want to be able to change their address dynamically.
is There  a way I can do this?
I do not want to use the environment. Because when I get build, I can not change api address

Comment: You can use something to store the api : if you're using oauth, you can store it inside user entity, else store it inside a variable, or context or inside a redux state, you can define the default value inside the code as default value or/and store it inYou shoud be more concise...

Answer (score 1):

Use the NODE_ENV env variable to check the environment

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set the API URL for prod
}
```

Set `NODE_ENV=production` when running your build script